# How do I use the PHP dotenv library without composer?

Tags: php, phpdotenv

I have for example this .env file in the root directory:

```
SERVERNAME="localhost" USERNAME="root" PASSWORD="" DATABASE="test"
```

This is my database connection file with PDO:

```
<?php
require_once("phpdotenv/src/Dotenv.php");
use Dotenv\Dotenv;
$dotenv = Dotenv\Dotenv::createImmutable(__DIR__);
$dotenv->load();

$servername = getenv("SERVERNAME");
$username = getenv("USERNAME");
$password = getenv("PASSWORD");
$dbname = getenv("DATABASE");

try {
    $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname;charset=utf8", $username, $password);
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo "Connection error: " . $e->getMessage();
    die();
}
```

I would like someone to tell me how to do it properly. It gives me fatal error. I don't want to use composer to use PHP dotenv. Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: It's designed to work with Composer. Using the PHP dotenv library without Composer is not recommended and would require manually including all the necessary files.

Comment: And how can I do on a web hosting that I can't use a dependency installer like composer and just download the PHP dotenv code from GitHub?